# How to executing function coming as a string in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, function

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'test2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
})
```

Now lets say i have the function as a string.

```
function_as_string="""
def func_x_2(df):
    for x in df.columns:
        df[x] = [df[x].values]*2
"""
```

Now i want to execute this function on the above df. How can i do that?

I tried using eval(). But its not working.

Comment: Why do you have your function's code as string ?

Comment: I will take user input as a function and execute that. Its one of the solutions I am thinking but I have other plans also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first

`exec('def f1(x): return x*x', globals())`

then you can call your function

`a = globals()['f1'](5)`

Comment: technically correct, but missing the required warnings: `exec` is __dangerous__.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers using `exec` or `eval` is danger. but what is dangerous in this particular case?

Comment: The dangerous part is that it is not just going to be used "in this particular case". The entire point of ``exec`` and ``eval`` is to evaluate dynamic, unknown code.

Comment: thank you. seems it dangerous but it will serve my purpose for now.